# How to place toggle input points on an Image?

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I want the user to tap on an image and a blob shows up and stores these points in the database. Very similar to the below image

[image: image attached]

from another app. Any ideas about what can be done? Is it overlaying on another picture or what?

Answer (score 0):

you can identify the color from the image and check with color if you click on image that time specific color code pick and checked with predefine color, if match then you perform you operation.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y); // x and y are coordinates
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
if(pixel == Color.RED){
       // color is red
    }
```